# Retrieve source of 'dynamic website' in java

Tags: java-8, jsoup

I am trying to retrieve the content of www.lifehack.org

I tried with Jsoup (fail) and then with JBrowserDriver (fail too) -> the content is always 'mask' by javascript.

Is there a way to retrieve the HTML content in java?

**Example of what is not working**:

POM:

```
<groupId>com.machinepublishers</groupId>
<artifactId>jbrowserdriver</artifactId>
<version>0.17.9</version>
```

Java:

```
    JBrowserDriver driver = new JBrowserDriver(Settings.builder()
            .proxy(proxy)
            .timezone(Timezone.PACIFIC_AUCKLAND)
            .userAgent(UserAgent.CHROME)
            .javascript(true)
            .ssl("compatible")
            .build());

    driver.get("http://www.lifehack.org");
    System.out.println(driver.getPageSource());
```

Comment: because the target site is wrote by `react` which means html is generated by [tag:react].

Comment: so there is no way to retrieve that?

Comment: there is no way to get the html content unless you run the javascript first.

Answer (score 0):

`JWebBrowserDriver` actually will retrieve and internally render the page with javascript, but you have to interact with the page via `JWebBrowserDriver` API.

For example, print all text links:

```
driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[. != '']"))
        .forEach(e -> System.out.println(e.getText()));
```